# "No nudity" signs in changing rooms in Doha?

Tags: local-customs, clothing, middle-east, cultural-awareness, qatar

The changing rooms for the gym and pool at the Doha hotel I'm currently in has a sign up saying

> Please respect local customs, and avoid nudity whilst using this changing room

However, it's laid out local a "normal" western style changing room - benches, lockers, showers etc, but no individual changing cubicles.

I had assumed that the sign would mean to use changing cubicles, but there weren't any! Swapping between trousers and swim wear in a wet shower cubicle didn't seem very practical either

What is the expected behaviour here? How are you expected to change between say trousers and swimwear in such a changing room, whilst respecting local customs about no nudity?

Comment: Doing it with a towel under your waist could be a solution. I don't actually know Doha but it could also mean you are expected to do it quickly and discreetly instead of wandering around naked while drying yourself as could happen elsewhere.

Comment: You know, before you asked this question I thought this was one of those "duh, just use a towel" answer - but then I realized it just may be me who does this :)

Comment: "no individual changing cubicles" - in various Western countries, that is absolutely *not* normal (or, if at all, a signal that the building is comparably old).

Comment: Was "laid out local a" supposed to be "laid out like a"?

Comment: "Nudity" doesn't even mean the same everywhere. I was in Busan, South Korea a few years ago and there was a sign in the hostel telling us not to be naked. It turned out to mean that even males should not be shirtless - let alone anything we in the west might consider nudity!

Comment: @Relaxed There were no towels available in the changing rooms - you collected your towel from poolside later! I suppose you could possibly go get one first, if that's what they meant?

Comment: Close your eyes while you change. If you can't see them, they can't see you.

Comment: Have you considered asking the management/attendant (discretely) what the intention is?

Answer (score 32):

What people usually do is putting on their boxers/underwear in the shower cubicle then come out and put on the rest. Some people do what Burhan described in the other answer as well.

Comment: So you walk around with wet undies? How do you dry off between your legs?

Comment: Dry yourself inside, not rocket science.

Answer (score 23):

Wrap a towel around your waist (or use a dressing gown/shower gown and face the locker) and then change your trunks/shorts.

Answer (score 4):

I would personally take that sign to mean 'no strutting around in the nude', aka it's acceptable to quickly change but not for longer than necessary.

Comment: This is an assumption, and may or may not be right though.